# Applying a custom file parser on a PySpark RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a set of custom log files, that I need to parse.  I am currently working in Azure Databricks, but am quite new in using PySpark.  The log files are hosted within an Azure Blob Storage Account, which is mounted to our Azure Databricks instance.

Log file example for the input:

```
Value_x: 1
Value_y: "Station"

col1;col2;col3;col4;
A1;B1;C1;D1;
A2;B2;C2;D2;
A3;B3;C3;D3;
```

Output that is a list of strings, but I can also work with a list of lists.

```
['A1;B1;C1;D1;1;station',
'A2;B2;C2;D2;1;station',
'A3;B3;C3;D3;1;station']
```

The snippet of code to apply these transformations.

```py
def custom_parser(file, content):
    content_ = content.replace('"', '').replace('\r', '').split('\n')
    content_ = [line for line in content_ if len(line) > 0]

    x = content_[0].split('Value_x:')[-1].strip()
    y = content_[0].split('Value_y:')[-1].strip()

    content_ = content_[3:]
    content_ = [line + ';'.join([x,y]) for line in content_]
    return content_

from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

sc = SparkContect.getOrCreate(SparkConf)

files = sc.wholeTextFiles('spam/eggs/').collect()

parsed_content = []
for file, content in files:
    parsed_content += custom_parser(file, content)
```

I have developed a custom_parser function to handle the content of these log files.  But I am left with some questions:

1. Can I apply this custom_parser action directly to the Spark RDD returned by sc.wholeTextFiles so I can use the parallelization features of Spark?
2. Is parsing the data in such an ad-hoc method the most performant method?

Comment: I assume that using sc.parallelize(files).map(custom_parser).collect() will allow me to use the parallelization of Spark and remove the final for-loop.  I need to modify the custom_parser to take a single *argv in that case

Comment: most likely you just need(untested): `sc.wholeTextFile('/spam/egg/').flatMap(lambda x: custom_parser(x[1]))`, remove the first argument `file` from custom_parser.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot apply your custom_parser action directly on sc.wholeTextFiles, but what you can do is to use custom_parser as map function, then after read your files and get RDD[String,String] (path,content) you can apply the custom_parser as rdd.map(custom_parser) and then write it where you need. In that way you will do your job in parallel, not like now that you are doing all in driver.

Comment: Would you use the sc.parallelize for this or can you straight up apply it?

My adjusted code now works in the following way sc.parallelize(files).map(custom_parser).collect()

Comment: Why do you need use parallelize for files? just use wholeTextFiles to read all files, it will return you RDD[String,String](first column is the filename second is filecontent), then apply you custom_parser on the second column, and then save it. try avoid doing collect, because it`ll bring all your data into the driver.

Comment: can you please elaborate on that?  I am not following, since I am quite new to PySpark

Comment: Would it be something in the format sc.wholeTextFiles(pathIn).map(custom_parser).saveAsTextFile(outFile) ?  Though the exact saving step might depend on my use case.